# How to run ASP.NET 4.0 version's Websites or Source codes on Microsoft Visual Web Developer 2008 Express Edition(ASP.net3.5), instead of VS 2010?

Tags: visual-studio-2008, web, asp.net-4.0, asp.net-3.5

I have a ASP.Net 4.0 version's Websites or Source Code files built on **ASP.NET 4.0** version, which requires Visual Studio **2010** Ultimate Edition to run this. But i have Windows XP SP2 and Microsoft Visual Web Developer 2008 Express Edition running on my PC. 
Is there any possible way to run those websites and source code built in **ASP.NET 4.0** version on my System with Windows XP SP2 and Microsoft Visual Web Developer 2008 Express Edition?